# Java: Why does my dot operator not work?

Tags: java

`.name` and `.bark` are not working

```
Dog  wildDogs[] = new Dog[3];
wildDogs[0]= new Dog();
wildDogs[0].name = "Fido";
wildDogs[0].bark();
```

Comment: what does your `Dog` class look like? also your array declaration is wrong

Comment: You need to explain clearly what exactly doesn't work. Post all the relevant information: compiler errors, exception messages, etc.

Comment: @XtremeBaumer Care to explain what's wrong with the array declaration? Look totally valid to me.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please create a full [mcve] and add the complete error message.

Comment: @lexicore my bad, ignore that part. Didn't knew that was valid as well. So far I've always seen and used `Dog[] dogs`

Comment: What is wrong with your question: first of all, it is unclear what the problem is. "Not working" does not tell us much. Explain which error are you getting. Next, the example is not complete. The `Dog` class is missing.

Comment: Please check if the class members of your Dog class is accessible in the class from which you are calling. (check if its private).

Answer (score 2):

The `.` sperator indicates that you are accessing a member of the object. In your case you are attempting to access a variable `name` and a method `bark()` but this can only happen if your class `Dog` actually contains these two properties. In other words your `Dog` class should look similar to this:

```
public class Dog
{
  public String name;

  public void bark()
  {
    // bark code goes here

    // example:
    System.out.println( "Wuff" );
  }
}
```

Also make sure that both are declared public. Read up more about scopes and what are there for in this [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html).